# How to read a 51gb log file?

Tags: linux, logging, text-editors

Well, it seems something went horrible wrong and now I do have a log file with a size larger than 51gb.
Are there any (linux) tools that can read/open files of that size?

I want to read the log file.

Comment: Just what do you mean by "read"? What are you trying to do with the log and what problem are you having? Is your Linux system 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`less` reads large files very well. It might try to count the line numbers, in which case it tells you to press `Ctrl-C` to stop counting them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can find a number of answers to your exact question (except the file was smaller, 2GB), on StackOverflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591723/linux-text-editor-for-working-with-huge-files). As you will see, nothing is truly satisfactory. And in your case, the situation is made even more serious by the obvious fact that the file will never fit into RAM, thus making random access a pain.

However, let me suggest an alternative. In your shoes, I wuold split the file in smaller chunks, to be edited separately, and then later re-assembled, like this:

```
 split -b 5M the_original_file
 cat xa* > the_reassembled_file.
```

From the Man page:

> SPLIT(1)                                         User Commands                                        SPLIT(1)

```
 NAME
   split - split a file into pieces

 SYNOPSIS
   split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]

 DESCRIPTION
   Output  fixed-size  pieces of INPUT to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...; default size is 1000 lines, and default
   PREFIX is 'x'.  With no INPUT, or when INPUT is -, read standard input.

   Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

   -a, --suffix-length=N
          generate suffixes of length N (default 2)

   --additional-suffix=SUFFIX
          append an additional SUFFIX to file names.

   -b, --bytes=SIZE
          put SIZE bytes per output file
```

Comment: The link you posted is for *editing* large files, while the question asks for *reading* large files. `less` works fine for viewing.

Comment: As @user287782 mentioned, `less` works flawless

Comment: @user287782 The question asks for a tool to (and I quote) read/open (end of quote). In standard Unix lingo, opening a file means the ability to write to it, not to read it.